# Passport doesn't save subdocument to req.user

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-local

**passport.js**

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user._id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User
    .findById(id).exec()
    .then(function(user) {
      done(null, user);
    }, done)
  ;
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  Local
    .findOne({ username: username })
    .select('username role hashedPassword')
    .exec()
    .then(function(local) {
      if (!local) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      var validPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(password, local.hashedPassword);
      if (!validPassword) {
        return done(null, false);
      }
      else {
        User
          .findOne({ local: local })
          .populate('local')
          .exec()
          .then(function(user) {
            console.log('user: ', user); // has subdocument
            return done(null, user);
          })
        ;
      }
    })
  ;
}));
```

**auth.routes.js**

```
router.get('/current-user', Auth.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  console.log('req.user: ', req.user); // doesn't have subdocument
  res.status(200).json(req.user);
});
```

**output**

```
user:  { _id: 55d8c6f7e1092f25bb761690,
  local:
   { _id: 55d8c6f7e1092f25bb76168f,
     username: 'a',
     role: 'user',
     __v: 0 },
  __v: 0 }
    ✓ Can log in with valid credentials
req.user:  { _id: 55d8c6f7e1092f25bb761690,
  local: 55d8c6f7e1092f25bb76168f,
  __v: 0 }
```

When I save the user into `req.user` (in `passport.js`), it has the subdocument `local`. But when I later try to access `req.user`, it gives me the `ObjectId` instead of the subdocument.

Why is this? How can I get the subdocument instead of the `ObjectId`?

Comment: How did you implement `deserializeUser()`?

Comment: @robertklep I updated my question with the code. Adding `populate('local')` to `deserializeUser()` fixed it. Thanks! Can you write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is roughly how Passport works:

- the strategy is called when a user hasn't been logged in yet; if the login was accepted, the user that you pass to the callback gets passed to `serializeUser()` to be stored (partially) in the session store. In your case, you're storing the user `_id` in the session store;
- `deserializeUser()` is called when a user is logged in (in other words, when there's a valid session). The session value (`_id`) is passed to it, and the value that gets passed to the callback is stored as `req.user`.

So you need to populate `local` from `deserializeUser()` too, otherwise it won't be available in `req.user`.